# Performance of asp.net mvc3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance-testing

I know a asp.net mvc3 app which crashes when 150+ users access the site at the same time. The architecture is load balanced with 2 servers with 4 GB RAM each. The w3wp process of this app in both servers takes more than 1.5 GB for the above scenario. Is this is an instance of suboptimal resources or poor coding?How a better code can perform with the given resources?There is on ms-sql server in the backend and there was no network related problem

Comment: Is the SQL server running on the same server?

Comment: no the sql server is a separate one

Comment: What does the log/error file say?

150 User with login procedure? AD or local profile (DB)?

With SSL or not?

It is a pure MVC architecture? wihtout IoC DI?

How big is a page load (MB) and How long is a page load?(min/sek)?More Info pls..thx

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework or nHibernate? In all cases you should probably profile the SQL server for Select n+1's. And in the right cases solve them with Eager loading. Something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527746/how-i-can-improve-asp-net-mvc-3-website-performance-by-using-cache

Comment: @danielglenn heres the answers..150 User with login procedure?yes..With SSL or not?with ssl.It is a pure MVC architecture? wihtout IoC DI?i dont know what that is can you post a link about it if possible (i am new to web programming). i dont hv error logs now will post when i get it. thx!

Comment: More details on error log would definitively help. In addition, architectural pattern and usage of tools besides of asp.net mvc framework are also very important factors. All in all, it is not a blame of Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: @Sat IoC Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control - Basic idea about IoC : it is like a Factory who create your objects - the IoC container knows when he needs to create the object (DI /service locator pattern)

Comment: @danielglenn there is a lot of these--"An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"btw i dont know if the architecture follows IoC...thx everyone for the replies!